# Change menu font wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, fonts

I'm trying to change the menu font for my Wordpress-site at persevere.nl.

[image]

I'm stuck at the style.css, while I'm pretty sure that's where the action is.
Because I'm pretty new at this I would really appreciate it is someone could show me how its done.

Comment: You want to change font size? font-family?

Comment: I'm trying to change the family

Answer (score 2):

You just need to target that CSS then.

```
#mainnav ul li a{
   font-family:"Droid Sans", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; //replace with what you want it to be
}
```

You can add it (the indented line) to the `style.css` where that code you circled is.

Comment: That's great, but I think my n00b ass coding skills are the problem. I can't find the line in style.css, only in the source code (html) of the site.